# VBA Excel: Turn Listbox Highlight Off

Tags: excel, listbox, vba

I have a `listbox` that I am using just to display text. I do not want to be able to highlight the rows in the `listbox`. Is there any way that I can turn off this feature?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to select items from the box or does that not matter?

Comment: Nope. Doesn't matter. I would, however, like to stick with the Listbox rather than using a label or something else because the amount of text in the box could exceed the size of the page, so I need scroll bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the listbox is giving you trouble, I recommend instead using a Textbox with the `Enabled` property set to `True`, `Locked` set to `True`, `MultiLine` set to `True`, `WordWrap` set to `True`, and the `ScrollBars` property set to `fmScrollBarsVertical`.  This will contain the text and allow scrolling without editing.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: How do I assign an array to a textbox? Can that be done?

Comment: Not technically, but what you can do is loop the array and add each item to the `TextBox.Text`, adding a `Chr(13)` after each item to send the box to the next line